# How to find which file caused the error?

Tags: python, django

I am upgrading a Django project from an old version to v1.8. The project worked with older version Django. But when I run it in v1.8 Django, I go the following errors.

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x10366a5f0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/foo/.virtualenvs/django_1p8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/foo/.virtualenvs/django_1p8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/foo/.virtualenvs/django_1p8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 252, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/Users/foo/.virtualenvs/django_1p8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/foo/.virtualenvs/django_1p8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/foo/.virtualenvs/django_1p8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/foo/.virtualenvs/django_1p8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 112, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named front
```

I have two folders in parallel,

```
back
front
```

The ***back*** folder handles the admin site and ***front*** handles front site. Now I have made the front part working.

Inside ***front*** folder, if I run

```
./manage.py runserver
```

the front site is running.

Now inside the ***back*** folder, I run

```
./manage.py runserver
```

It gives me the above errors.

There are a few files in the ***back*** folder refers to ***front app***. I am not sure which one caused this error.

Inside the ***back*** folder, I have the following files

```
back
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── settings.py
├── settings.pyc
├── urls.py
└── wsgi.py
```

In the ***settings.py***, I have following.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.sites',
     'front.news',
)
```

I am not sure if the error was caused by this ***front.news***. So I removed change it from

```
'front.news'
```

to

```
'news'
```

Now the error message become

```
ImportError: No module named news
```

So how can I include the app from the other folder ***front***?

Thanks.

Comment: As I see from the question, back and front are two different websites, not just web applications. For you to use a webapp from some other website, the way that I know is include front in the PYTHONPATH of back project.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right. I may miss the path.